# в изучении Python on csv file получил Key Error : 'home'

Tags: python, csv

учебный код

```
import csv

students = []
with open("names.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        students.append({"name": row["name"], "home":row["home"] })


for student in sorted(students, key=lambda student: student["name"]):
    print(f"{student['name']} is from {student['home']}")
```

В names.csv

```
names, home
Nickola, Denver
Dan, "Moscow The New Arbat"
Peter, "New York Queens Borough"
Andre, San Diego
```

Comment: В csv после запятых не должно быть пробелов. Все кроме самих запятых - это часть значения, поэтому имя колонки у вас на самом деле не "home", а " home". Ну и подозреваю должно быть или name в коде и в csv, или names.

Comment: спасибо большое! исправил и все заработало! я так благодарен, это мой первый опыт обращения за помощью и так оперативно. Всем спасибо и stackoverflow really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас опечатки в коде.

1. В CSV после запятых не должно быть запятых.
2. У вас опечатка в `names.csv`, в файле нужно заменить `names` на `name`.

Исправленный код:

CSV:

```
name,home
Nickola,Denver
Dan,"Moscow The New Arbat"
Peter,"New York Queens Borough"
Andre,San Diego
```

Python:

```py
import csv

students = []
with open("names.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        students.append({"name": row["name"], "home":row["home"] })


for student in sorted(students, key=lambda student: student["name"]):
    print(f"{student['name']} is from {student['home']}")
```